# Flask SQLAlchemy query, specify column names

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How do I specify the column that I want in my query using a model (it selects all columns by default)? I know how to do this with the sqlalchmey session: `session.query(self.col1)`, but how do I do it with with models?  I can't do `SomeModel.query()`. Is there a way?

Answer (score 329, accepted):

You can use the `with_entities()` method to restrict which columns you'd like to return in the result. ([documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_entities))

```
result = SomeModel.query.with_entities(SomeModel.col1, SomeModel.col2)
```

Depending on your requirements, you may also find [deferreds](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_columns.html#deferred) useful.  They allow you to return the full object but restrict the columns that come over the wire.

Comment: with_entities() makes all() yield tuples of column values, not objects!

Comment: kolypto: It yields whatever you ask it to yield.  SomeModel.query.with_entities(SomeModel) would yield the object.  Just like session.query(SomeModel.col1, SomeModel.col2) would yield tuples of column values.  Deferreds are what you'd use if you don't want columns coming over the wire, but you want the whole object anyway.

Comment: Thanks it works. But how could we assign alias to the field ? Because in my case, I'm using JOIN and conflict `ID` field which is present in both table

Comment: Yeah I have same question with @MitulShah, how to set alias?

Comment: For alias, view this brief answer below ie. use `.label()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/11535992/248616

Comment: Note that result will just be a query, i.e. `flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery object`. You still need to execute the query - https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/queries/#querying-records. For example, you can call `result.all()` or `result.first()`.

Comment: BTW: at recent versions `with_entities` yields `Row` instances.

Comment: on sqlalchemy [1.3.19](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/releases/tag/rel_1_3_19) (almost 3 years ago), `.query.with_entities(...)` returns `sqlalchemy.util._collections.result`

Comment: how to get data from it: `[value[0] for value in db.session.query(Book).with_entities(Book.author_id)][0]`

Answer (score 109):

```
session.query().with_entities(SomeModel.col1)
```

is the same as

```
session.query(SomeModel.col1)
```

for alias, we can use .label()

```
session.query(SomeModel.col1.label('some alias name'))
```

Comment: The second one both sounds more logical and is shorter — win/win

Comment: The first (and third) options are the best, by far, if you want to reuse existing query objects, especially in the case of performing multiple complex subqueries.

Answer (score 84):

You can use [load_only](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_columns.html#load-only-and-wildcard-options) function:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import load_only

fields = ['name', 'addr', 'phone', 'url']
companies = session.query(SomeModel).options(load_only(*fields)).all()
```

Comment: This solution is the best one as it is still working as an Object not only the list of results.

Comment: Kudos to you for this solution. It has many advantages: - return exactly the same type of object as `.first()` and `.one()` (that will lazy/eager load fields and relations), - can be set as query component

Comment: the code is clean but the sql query selects all fields from the database. I have used `with_entities` as given in the accepted answer and the query selected only that fields/.

Comment: This returns the whole object.

Comment: This is not working, is returning the entire object.

Comment: It is returning the id value which is not required for me

Comment: What is the benefit of this solution? This returns whole object, but in essence, the columns we need actually. So, if we don't retrieve data from all columns so is this fact makes this solution more efficient in terms of performance?

Answer (score 11):

You can use `Model.query`, because the `Model` (or usually its base class, especially in cases where declarative extension is used) is assigned [`Sesssion.query_property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.ScopedSession.query_property). In this case the `Model.query` is equivalent to `Session.query(Model)`.

I am not aware of the way to modify the columns returned by the query (except by adding more using [`add_columns()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.add_columns)).
So your best shot is to use the `Session.query(Model.col1, Model.col2, ...)` (as already shown by Salil).

Comment: I believe there may also be a way to do this with a list of columns for query values() too, http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.values - but the syntactic sugar for the list eludes me at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Query.values, [Query.values](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html?highlight=values#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.values)

`session.query(SomeModel).values('id', 'user')`

Answer (score 3):

I usually use this snippet:

```
fields = ["col1", "col2", ...]\
session.query(map(lambda x: getattr(SomeModel.c, x), fields))
```

Comment: I still had to use `add_columns`; not sure what is missing, but the idea is nice.

Answer (score 2):

`result = ModalName.query.add_columns(ModelName.colname, ModelName.colname)`

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more context for your answer? Why and how it works can help other people with similar problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As `session.query(SomeModel.col1)` returns an array of tuples like this `[('value_1',),('value_2',)]` if you want t cast the result to a **plain array** you can do it by using one of the following statements:

```
values = [value[0] for value in session.query(SomeModel.col1)]
values = [model.col1 for model in session.query(SomeModel).options(load_only('col1'))]
```

Result:

```
 ['value_1', 'value_2']
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate syntax to fetch entity with specific columns:

```
any_query.with_entities(Entity).options(load_only(Entity.col))
```