# Sqlalchemy - how do I generate a query that returns only a field from a jsonb column

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, jsonb

I'm trying to find the best way to generate a sql query that gets me a specific field from a jsonb column from my db. I want to generate a query like this:

```
select images->'main' from scenes where id = 1;
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530196/flask-sqlalchemy-query-specify-column-names) reference for using with_entities, and this generates the query correctly:

```
>>> x = Scene.query.with_entities(Scene.images['main']).first()                                                                                                                                                                        
2016-09-22 18:57:01,825 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT scenes.images -> %(images_1)s AS anon_1                                                                                                                              
FROM scenes                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 LIMIT %(param_1)s                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
2016-09-22 18:57:01,826 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'param_1': 1, 'images_1': 'main'}
```

However, it's returning the result as a tuple rather than a model object:

```
>>> x                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
([{u'url': u'foo.jpg', u'priority': 1}],)
```

I considered using [load_only](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_columns.html#load-only-cols), but this API doesn't seem to have a way of specifying jsonb fields of a column, but only an entire column name.

Is there a way to generate the query and have the model object as the return value?

Comment: Well, if it returned a model object, where do you expect your field do be on that object?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Scene` is an ORM class, you can use [Session.query()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.query) to either return the value as a tuple

```py
x = session.query(Scene.images['main']).filter_by(id=1).one()
print x
```

```sql
SELECT images->'main' FROM scenes WHERE id = 1;
```

or the model object (instance of `Scene`)

```py
scene = session.query(Scene).filter_by(id=1).one()
print scene.images['main']
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM scenes WHERE id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = db.session.query(Scene.images['main'].label('main_image')).first()
print(x.main_image)
```