# Get values in Flask Query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How do you get values from a Flask Query?

Here's what I'm trying:

`batch_num_options = Ticket.query.values('batch_num').all()`

and this produces the error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "batch_num" does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT batch_num

But if I `psql` into my `Ticket` table I can clearly see that `batch_num` is a column.

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530196/flask-sqlalchemy-query-specify-column-names

Answer (score 0):

I use it like this

```
our_model_object.query.with_entities(Your_model.your_attribute)
```

in your example, getting the first row only

```
batch_num = Ticket.query.with_entities(Ticket.batch_num).first() # or all() if you want all rows
print(batch_num)
```

This will return just the specified column, in this case batch_num. Or you can query the complete row, like this

```
ticket = Ticket.query.first() # use all if you want to get all rows
print(ticket.batch_num)
```