# SQLAlchemy: retrieve records by exact matching on keys in nested JSONB field

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy, jsonb

Let's say I have a table named `Table`, which contains a JSONB field `data`. One of the records (record 1) has the following JSON object stored there:

```
{
    "A": {},
    "B": {}
}
```

Another record (record 2) has the following JSONB object stored:

```
{
    "A": {},
    "B": {},
    "C": {}
}
```

I am struggling to define a way to find records by doing an exact filtering on the keys in the `data` field. For example, I would like to retrieve the record with only the keys **"A"** and **"B"**, in the `data` field, i.e. record 1.

I have tried the SQLAlchemy's `JSONB` type comparator [methods](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB) such as the [contains()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB.Comparator.contains) method but this would return both records in case of the following Python query:

```
Session().query(Table).filter(Table.data.contains({"A": {}, "B": {}})).all()
```

Is it possible to achieve an exact filtering on (a list of) keys with the available SQLAlchemy filters? Any thoughts are welcome. Many thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask SQLAlchemy query, specify column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530196/flask-sqlalchemy-query-specify-column-names)

Comment: @sahasrara62 They are different questions so unfortunately it does not answer my question. I am looking specifically for a way to check if the keys in a JSONB field exactly match with a list of keys.

Comment: so you are trying to filter out data from the data object (here json ) stored in the database ? i dont think you can directly do that, you need to fetch all first then iterate through them  and apply the condition

Comment: Not exactly filtering out data from the data object (jsonb) but rather filtering records based on the keys in the data object. So basically I am looking for something along the lines of the follow filtering functionality: ```filter(Table.data.keys() == ['A', 'B'])```. This does not work because the JSONB object data does not have a function ```keys()```

Answer (score 0):

The `?` operator returns true if the string exists as a top-level key.

The `-` operator deletes key/value pairs from the left operand.

You can combine these like this:

```
select data from Table 
where data ? 'A' and data ? 'B' and (data - 'A') - 'B' = '{}';
```

In English, get records that

- contain 'A' and 'B' keys: `data ? 'A' and data ? 'B'`
- are empty if you remove 'A' and 'B' keys (ie contain no other keys): `(data - 'A') - 'B' = '{}'`